# Spring Aspect recursion call

Tags: spring-aop, aspect

I have to create aspect , that should after throwing custom exception invoke  the method with the same arguments again , where this exception was thrown , but method recursion call must be not more 5 times. Is it ever  possible to do that?

Comment: What's throwing the exception? The advice or the advised method? Just make an `@Around` advice that loops max 5 times, invoking the advised method.

Answer (score 0):

I used annotation to be more fluent:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
/** Annotation for ascect using to define how many times try running     annotated method */

public @interface TryMultiplyTimes {
    /** define how many time try running method */
    int times() default 0;
}
```

On method witch you want try multi-times running get annotation with declaration how many times you need (in my case is DAO class):

```
@Component
public class CustomerDAOImpl{

@TryMultiplyTimes(times=5)
public void addCustomerThrowException(String text) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("addCustomerThrowException() is running with args: "+text);
    throw new Exception("Generic Error");
}
```

And most important part: aspect. My aspect based on annotation Around trying call method. Aspect attempts call method, when get exception, check if can call method more times; if not, thows exception. Key is hashCode of calss and method, to distinguish calling this same method by differend entities.

```
@Aspect
public class MultiTimesAspect {

@Around("@annotation(multiTimeAnnotation)")
public void aspectMultiTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, TryMultiplyTimes multiTimeAnnotation)throws Throwable {

    System.out.println("***********************************************");
    System.out.println("before running method: "+ joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

    try {
        joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs()); //running method with it's args
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        //if method throws exception:
        int times = multiTimeAnnotation.times();//get how many times can trying
        String key = createKey(joinPoint);      //create key (class hashCode and method hashCode) for managing map 
        if (repeatsMap.get(key) == null) {
            repeatsMap.put(key, 1);             //if method called first time
        }

        int proceeded = repeatsMap.get(key);
        if (proceeded < times) {
            //if can try more times preincrement reapeats and recursively call aspect
            repeatsMap.replace(key, ++proceeded);
            aspectMultiTime(joinPoint, multiTimeAnnotation);
        } else {
            //if can't call method anymore, delete from map key and throws excetion
            repeatsMap.remove(key);
            throw e;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("after running method: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("***********************************************");
}

private String createKey(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append(joinPoint.getTarget().toString()).append(".")
            .append(joinPoint.getThis().toString());
    return buffer.toString();
}
}
```

And test class

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String... args){
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "spring-aop.xml");
    CustomerDAOImpl customer= (CustomerDAOImpl) ctx.getBean("customerBo");
    try {
        customer.addCustomerThrowException("**TEST**");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```